# ASP.NET MVC with Web API Architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, architecture

Gurus,
Am newbie in MVC. I am developing a web application for an Order Management System. I have devised architecture to have the following projects as part of my solution:

1. Client (Presentation layer, MVC)
2. CrossCuttingServices ( framework components like logging, caching, Data, Class lib)
3. Data (Entity framework layer for DB interation, C# class lib)
4. Services (Services layer to be consumed by Presentation, Web API)

Q1. My question is, where should I create my entity classes or Models, which will be used across Presentation to Services to Data? Either in models of Presentation or in Web API service layer or as a seperate project (C# library)?

Q2. Also, let me know is there any generic implementation to invoke WebAPI services from Presentation controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to go with Architecture like 
1. JS Enabled Presentation (webform or only HTML + JS)
2. Web API (Controller calling data services (EF+Repo) as my service layer for data, it can support my browser based front end and devices

Let me know any drawbacks on same

Answer (score 0):

Q1: You will be using the same entities throughout the entire solution so I recommend storing them in your Data project since it keeps all database related stuff bundled together separately from the remaining logic.

Q2: You could always send a request to the APIs to get the resulting data, it's essentially what they're there for.

Comment: in that case for Q1, I need t reference DAta project in MVC presentation layer. Isn't it not bad design

Comment: You still need to reference the project but it's not bad design. In every project you can focus more on what that task is about. Also in case of a rapid growth of tables you don't end up cluttering the main project.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem, with a pretty complex domain model. As a result we have opted for

- data entity models defined in a separate DomainModel DLL
- UI mapper classes that map from datamodel to UI models
- WebAPI mapper classes that map from datamodel to WebAPI models

An example of why we want this?

- UI has concept of distributor catalogue item, which is a specialisation of catalogue item
- WebAPI uses the basic catalogueitem datamodel, but then returns different data based on the specific resource  [eg a search URL returns item ID and basic info; an item lookup URL returns full details for the catalogue item.

As a result of the above, the catalogueitem in our DomainModel is the full complete object, which the different "clients" then map as they see fit.
[This is in line with what [Filip Stankovski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2309194/filip-stankovski) said above]